# Having trouble to send data from mongodb to web page

Tags: html, ejs

I want to send data about shopping cart from mongoDB to front-end page, use I use Koa and EJS engine, and I sure I have successfully get data from database. But in web page, it shown undefined

```
router.get('/cart', loadCart)

async function loadCart(ctx){
    let userid = ctx.session.userID
    let c_data = await C.getCart(userid)
    console.log(typeof(c_data))
    await ctx.render('cart',{ 
        userid, c_data
    })
}
```

code in html

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= c_data %>" id="data">

function loadCart(){
    let content = ""
    let c_data = document.getElementById('data').value
    c_data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.name)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add render settings like bellow?

```
    render(app, {
    root: templatesPath,
    layout: 'template',
    viewExt: 'html',
    cache: false,
    debug: false,
    async: true
})
```

I think two properties here are important:  root and layout.